# Подписка на атрибуты

Tags: php, mysql, rabbitmq

Интересует архитектура подписки на атрибуты. К примеру, каждый день приходит 1000 событий. У каждого события есть список атрибутов (к примеру, регион отправки, город отправки, регион получения, город получения)

Есть пользователи, которые хотя получать эти события, но только если атрибуты события совпадают с атрибутами пользователя.

Как быстро проверять события для всех пользователей и быстро отправлять уведомления?

Пользователей > 100 000

---

По порядку:
1. Атрибуты да, всегда одни и те же, только значения меняются. Забыл страну. Т.е. такие: Страна отправки, регион отправки, город отправки, СТрана получения, регион получения, город получения.

2. Если пользователь у себя указывает все 6 атрибутов(наверно лучше сказать маршрут), то оповещаем только если есть точное совпадение + если есть обратный маршрут:
   `# # # @ @ @`
   `@ @ @ # # #`

где `#` - это "откуда", `@` - куда.

Например пришло 2 события с атрибутами:
Россия Московская обл. Королев - Россия Смоленская обл. Гагарин
Россия Смоленская обл. Гагарин - Россия Московская обл. Королев

У пользователя стоит такое:
Россия Московская обл. Королев - Россия Смоленская обл. Гагарин
Россия Московская обл - Россия Смоленская обл

Оба события должны к нему попасть.
Если указан просто страна и регион - то все события с городами из этого региона тоже должны попадать

Хранится в базе в таблице as columns:
События
`event | country_from | region_from | ... | city_to`

пользователи
`user_id | country_from | ... | city_to`

Comment: Атрибуты всегда одни и те же используются? Или могут различаться от события к событию? "если атрибуты события совпадают с атрибутами пользователя" - это как? Полностью или частично? И как с пересечениями? Например у пользователя аттрибуты `1, 2`, а у двух событий атрибуты `1` и `1, 3`, соответственно. Об этих событиях надо оповещать? Как атрибуты пользователя и событий хранятся? И 100К - это мало

Comment: Ответил в вопросе

Comment: есть у кого идеи?